# Sending a mail from R using mailR package getting the error

Tags: r, sendmailr

I am trying to sending a mail from R using **`mailR`** package but getting the error.

My code :

```
subject <- "Montly Report"
today<-Sys.Date()
fileName <- sprintf('./DailyReports/LaunchDaily_%s.html', format(today, format = "%d-%m-%y"))
body <- "Testing Document"

send.mail(from = from,
          to = to,
          cc = cc,
          bcc = bcc,
          subject = subject,
          attach.files = fileName,
          html = T,
          inline = T,
          body = body,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "email id",            
                      passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = T,
          send = T
)
```

and error :

```
Error in .jnew("org.apache.commons.mail.ImageHtmlEmail") : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
```

i have tried to search in **google** and **github** also but not getting the fix to the prob.

**Note:** : [Link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mailR/versions/0.4.1) i have gone through the Link and tried also the code but not worked for me.

System OS : Ubuntu 18.04,
R Studio  : 1.1.456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is raised due to the mismatch of Java version error.

For Ubuntu users need to install Oracle Java instead of JDK version and need to set home path properly.

Then google account setting need to be surely lessappsecure to 'turn ON'.

to set java..type in Terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
javac -version
```

**OUTPUT**

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

and test once in R like java path is correctly working or not with `rJava`

try to run below **libraries**

```
library(rJava)
library(mailR)
```

if both libraries will run without any errors then **JAVA** is correctly working.

Successful Message :

After completion of sending the mail in r session you will get the message like below :

```
[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.commons.mail.ImageHtmlEmail@32709393}"
```

**NOTE:**

Try to careful while installing and setting the path properly in Ubuntu itself.

Comment: y can't u try with sendR package?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to avoid that kind of dependency bug. I suggest dropping tha package `mailR` in favor of `emayili` which do not cause that kind of problems.

[emayili GitHub page](https://github.com/datawookie/emayili)

Answer (score 0):

`javax.activation` (Java Activation Framework (JAF)) was removed from the core JRE bundle in Java 9. The `sendR` library was built against Java 8. You're very likely using a newer version of Java that doesn't have JAF.

Three options:

- Use Java 8
- Add the [JAF jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation) to your classpath
- Use a different/better/newer email library, ideally one that doesn't even rely on Java, such as [`emayili`](https://github.com/datawookie/emayili)

The third would be my recommendation.